# Adding images to Service Report in FSL

Tags: fsl

Has anyone been able to add a multiple images to the Service Report/Template? if anyone has any approaches please share.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you cannot add images to a service report template. Kindly review limitation [here](https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000GdbgvUAB/ability-to-add-images-to-a-service-report-template-on-the-fly-in-fsl-mobile-app) and vote.

However, you can check [workaround](https://curiouslyservicemax.medium.com/add-image-to-salesforces-fsl-service-report-3d7b8e57ad27) mentioned.

Comment: I see the ideaExchange and also the workaround in my case I have upload multiple images and when the service report print it should also print along with the report.

Comment: Can you pls review example I see there is possibility to generate image within the service report :)